# HTML page is appearing different in Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

Hey guys, i have recently created a HTML page but it is appearing differently in Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer. I have uploaded the page on ripway. Here is the URL http://h1.ripway.com/gurusmith/My%20site/Index/index.html

Please watch the page in both Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox and after watching you will find that the page is appearing fine in Internet Explorer but not in Mozilla Firefox. Can anyone tell where i have made the problems. If anyone can edit the source code and post the correct source code here which works fine in both the browsers then i will be really thankful to you.

Sorry, i can't post the source code and the outputs due to restrictions but i have given the link above for the page. So please do visit it and help me.

Answer (score 3):

Your page is not even remotely valid HTML. For one thing, you have two `body` elements.

Check out [W3C Validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://h1.ripway.com/gurusmith/My%2520site/Index/index.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.2) of your page for more problems.

If a browser gets invalid HTML it makes its best guess at what the DOM should be (as opposed to a deterministic interpretation). Since browsers are designed by independent teams, these interpretations will differ. Then, when it comes to applying CSS, variations are bond to occur.

Get your HTML in order and then see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of IE are known to display pages slightly differently than most "modern" browsers. A quick Google search turned up the following lists of common differences:

http://www.wipeout44.com/brain_food/css_ie_bug_fixes.asp

http://css-tricks.com/ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/